# parsing a line of text to get a specific number

Tags: python, parsing

I have a line of text in the form `"    some spaces  variable =         7     =    '0x07'  some more data"`

I want to parse it and get the number 7 from "some variable = 7".  How can this be done in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a simpler solution, avoiding regular expressions.

Split on '=' and get the value at the position you expect

```
text = 'some spaces variable = 7 = ...'
if '=' in text:
    chunks = text.split('=')
    assignedval = chunks[1]#second value, 7
    print 'assigned value is', assignedval
else:
    print 'no assignment in line'
```

Comment: While there's nothing wrong(?) with learning regex, and they can be useful, I am terribly fond of this quote: You have a matching problem, so you think "Aha! I'll use a regex!" Now you have two problems.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

Essentially, you create an expression that goes something like `"variable = (\d+)"`, do a match, and then take the first group, which will give you the string 7. You can then convert it to an int.

Read the tutorial in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Basic regex code snippet to find numbers in a string.

```
>>> import re
>>> input = " some spaces variable = 7 = '0x07' some more data"
>>> nums = re.findall("[0-9]*", input)
>>> nums = [i for i in nums if i]  # remove empty strings
>>> nums
['7', '0', '07']
```

Check out the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) and [How-To](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html#regex-howto) on python.org.